# How to add an object with texture inside another object?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am trying to make an eye. I made the iris in Photoshop and now I am trying to add it to a UV Sphere. I would like to make a realistic eye but maybe I am not in the correct way. Any thoughts? This is my work so far:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by adding object to another object ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you need is to model a proper eye. Like so:
[image: eye_model]

The outer part is 0.1cm away from the inner in this case.
[image: distance]

The **outer part** needs to be **refractive** (or even just transparent) and it will also need **specular** as it will catch the high spec of the eye.

Depending on the render budget you have you can add SSS to the inner part. I did in this case but the difference here is subtle. In this case i'm aiming cartoon semirealistic eye but the principles are pretty much the same for any eye.

You now have to UV unwrap the inner part. Easy, divide the eye in two parts on its XZ plane center and Unwrap.

[image: unwrap_eye]

Now you can add the diffuse texture to the inner part of the eye, but note that for a proper eye render you will need more than just a diffuse shader.
Personally I add a specular map only to the iris using an high IOR and roughness value, a bump (or displacement if needed) map aswell.

Here is the final graph of my setup:
[image: graph_in]
[image: graph_out]
and a little GIF preview:
[image: gif-PREVIEW]

Comment: Consider including a .blend file so that the user does not have to build all this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Akelian. It is so wonderful. When you say "You now have to UV unwrap the inner part. Easy, divide the eye in two parts on its XZ plane center and Unwrap." What do you mean?  Sorry I don't have enough knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: @Akelian. For sure I will follow your stepts but I want to  compare with iris makes in photoshop so I'll make the eye but how can I add the iris? Thank you again.

Comment: i'll update the answer in the hour ;)

Comment: @Meri I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

### Idle Chit-chat

If you are going for realism, I would suggest switching to Cycles Render (much faster, newer, better, AND built for photorealism). So, this tutorial is for Cycles. This will be the final result:

[image]

### Materials

I will use a sphere to represent the eye (smooth shading), and the following eye texture from [Google](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Eye_I.jpg) (full size linked) in my demonstration.

[image]

With the sphere selected, go to the *Materials* tab in the *Properties panel*. *+ New* a material to the sphere. Go into the *Node editor*, and use the setup shown.

[image]

Now, go to the sphere in the *3D Viewport*. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode, <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to front view, and <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to orthographic view. Enter *Face Select Mode*. Select these faces:

[image]

Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select *Project from View (Bounds)*. Split the screen into a *3D Viewport* and a *UV Image Editor* by dragging the marks in the top-right corner to the left. Make sure you are still in edit mode. Open the image of the eye through the toolbar at the bottom of the *UV Image Editor*. The orange should already be aligned over the eye.

### Final Notes

I added the nodes at the bottom to create red veins in the eye. It's more realistic.

Here is the finished .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shady, but that will not provide realistic result. You have to reproduce the way a real eye is made. I'm preparing a proper answer.

Comment: There is a place where it should have 3 buttons: a dropdown, a + New, and an open. Also, if this helped, consider accepting.

Comment: Thanks @Shady but I think you didn't finish. Now the eye is unwrap. Please can you go on? Because I want to make the pupil part. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: if I can help. I saw this tutorial https://vimeo.com/2830890 but I can't follow because I don't see anything and also the man doesn't talk much.

Comment: I did finish. If u did the node setup, everything should be good.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Just copy it or download the .blend file.

Comment: Try to avoid explicit tutorials. The idea is for this answer to be helpful to as many people as possible. I think the human eye is common enough that this will still be useful to a lot of people, but try to be generic.

Comment: Cycles is not faster than Internal

Comment: Perhaps consider accepting?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. One approach would be to select your UV Sphere (Eyeball), <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*, and select a ring of vertices

[image]

From here, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and choose *Cursor to Selected* from the drop down menu. Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Object Mode* and select your iris object. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select *Selection to Cursor* from the drop down menu. **NOTE:** the origin of your iris object needs to be in the middle of it's geometry. If it’s not, select the iris object in *Object Mode* and choose the *Set Origin* drop down menu in the tool bar (Pressing <kbd>T</kbd> with your cursor in the 3D Viewport will toggle the tool bar on and off) and choose *Origin to Geometry* from the drop down menu.

[image]

Then in *Object Mode*, you can select the iris object and while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> key select the UV Sphere and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the meshes **or** in “Object Mode” you can select the iris object and while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the UV Sphere and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent the iris object to the UV Sphere.